# Nuxt3: What's the difference between "useFetch" and "useAsyncData"

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have been trying to understand the difference between these two compostables so I can use them the right way in my app
according to [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#useasyncdata)

> In brief, useFetch receives a URL and gets that data, whereas
> useAsyncData might have more complex logic. useFetch(url) is nearly
> equivalent to useAsyncData(url, () => $fetch(url)) - it's developer
> experience sugar for the most common use case.

it says that `useAsyncData` might have more complex logic, but what does that mean?

This is a testing code I used with both composable but I didn't notice any difference

```
<template>

  <div v-show="pendingFetch" class="text-rose-700">LOADING useFetch ...</div>
  <pre>{{ productsUseFetch }}</pre>

 <h1>=====================================================</h1>

  <div v-show="pendingAsyncData" class="text-green-500">
    LOADING asyncData ...
  </div>
  <pre>{{ productsUseAsyncData }}</pre>

</template>

<script setup>
const { data: productsUseFetch, pendingFetch, errorFetch } = await useFetch(
  "https://fakestoreapi.com/products"
);

const {
  data: productsUseAsyncData,
  pendingAsyncData,
  errorAsyncData,
} = await useAsyncData("testFetch", () =>
  $fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument of [`useFetch`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) is only a URL to fetch from.

In [`useAsyncData`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data) you passing in a handler function that can even take `nuxtApp` as an argument and returns async data after doing whatever you need. I don't have any real world example right now, but having a choice between a plain parameter or a potentially complex function sounds like a difference to me.

Your test code is literally what the docs say: `useFetch(url) is nearly equivalent to useAsyncData(url, () => $fetch(url))`

Comment: I see, from the SSR perspective do they have any difference? does one have any advantages in terms of SEO or performance over the other?

Answer (score 0):

the difference between useFetch and useAsyncData is that the useAsyncData can employee another data fetching composables that you want to make it server side friendly where as useFetch  accept url for fetching data for example
for useFetch

1. useFetch(ur)
   for useAsyncData
2. useAsyncData(()=>$fetch(url))
3. useAsyncData(()=>useQuery(query,anothe options))  if you are familiar with [Graphql](https://graphql.org/) [apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/)

[ForMore](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching)